# why do my shapes get generated 150pxs to the left with every new shape?

Tags: javascript, function, attributes, setinterval, createelement

im working on this game and have finally figured out how to rewrite my code to a minimal example and i am quiet proud of how much code i cut out for this example. so my code herestarts running when clicking on the screen, after you click, my createShape1() function runs, creating a grey rectangle. It begins to drop down the screen and when it hits the bottom, CreateShape1() is called again starting the whole process over again. however, the second shape should be in the same position as the first shape, but it is shifted 150pxs to the left and eventually resets and shifts down.
This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tetris</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleSheets/main.css">
    <script src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" style= "height: 650px; width: 500px; background: black; position: relative">
      <div class= "grid">
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.grid {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg,transparent,transparent 49px,#88F 49px,#88F 50px),
                    repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg,transparent,transparent 49px,#88F 49px,#88F 50px);
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 651px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 501px;
}
```

JS:

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
countO = 0;
function createShape1() {
  var endB1 = 650;
  var newEndB = endB1; //used to set boundaries bottom
  var elem = document.getElementById("container");
  var outer = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "svg"); //creates full transparent shape
  countO++;
  elem.append(outer);
  outer.id = "outer" + countO;
  outer.style.background = "grey";
  outer.style.height = "100px";
  outer.style.width = "150px";
  outer.style.left = "150px";
  outer.style.top = "0px";
  outer.style.position = "relative";
  outer.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)"
  var t = setInterval(down, 100); // calls down() function every second
  var yPos = parseInt(outer.style.top);
  var h = parseInt(outer.style.height);
  var ymath = yPos + h;
  function down() {  // moves shape down by 50px
    if (ymath < newEndB) {
      yPos += 50;
      ymath = yPos + h;
      outer.style.top = yPos +'px';

    } else {
      clearInterval(t);
    }
  }
};

var shapes = [createShape1];
function randShape() {
  shapes[0]();
};

window.addEventListener("click", startGame, {once: true})

function startGame() {
  randShape()
  var t = setInterval(randShape, 1200)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that your script adds a new element on each call. Since they have `position:relative`, they are generated next to each other and can't intersect. Even if you move them around with the `down()` function, they are just visually moved relative to their original position and technically still occupy the space they were generated in. Try changing

```
outer.style.position = "relative";
```

to

```
outer.style.position = "absolute";
```

[Here is a pen](https://codepen.io/SwimmerF/pen/zYxwgwE)

Alternatively, you could make the script remove the previous block before creating the new one, that should work aswell.

Comment: its a Tetris game so i dont want to remove the shape. but i have learned a major lesson in minimal example size. i was stumped for 2 weeks and no one even bothered looking at my code and now that i shrunk it here you fixed in 2 mins.